# How to change UITabBar background color?

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I have been following tutorials and it seems that when the instructor set up the tabbar, it automatically has color.
This tutorials was made in different xcode version, so It could be why it shows the different result.

[image]

As you can see, the background color and the tabbar background color is the same.

What I want is

[image]

I just put the tabbar background color to light gray.
Is this how it is supposed to be done or am I missing something?

[image]
This is what I am expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewDidLoad(), add:

```
let backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
if let tabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar {
    tabBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
}
```

Comment: Or, more simply: `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = .gray`